# Error in ocrFile function in AbbyyR package

Tags: r, ocr, abbyy

While I was using Abbyy cloud SDK for OCR, I keep on getting the error below when I try to use the ocrFile function which is inside the AbbyyR package.

" Error in curl_download(finishedlist$resultUrl[res$id == finishedlist$id],  : 
  Argument 'url' must be string. "

When I send the files to the cloud and process them everything works fine but when the cloud returns the files there is a problem in downloading them. I thought that it might be a network or certificate problem but I can't solve the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in source code, it needs as.character() function for url.
I updated ocrFile function as follows:

```
    install.packages("curl")
    library(curl)

    new_ocrFile<-function (file_path = "", output_dir = "./", exportFormat = c("txt", 
                                                                  "txtUnstructured", "rtf", "docx", "xlsx", "pptx", "pdfSearchable", 
                                                                  "pdfTextAndImages", "pdfa", "xml", "xmlForCorrectedImage", 
                                                                  "alto"), save_to_file = TRUE) 
    {
      exportFormat <- match.arg(exportFormat)
      res <- processImage(file_path = file_path, exportFormat = exportFormat)
      while (!(any(as.character(res$id) == as.character(listFinishedTasks()$id)))) {
        Sys.sleep(1)
      }
      finishedlist <- listFinishedTasks()
      res$id <- as.character(res$id)
      finishedlist$id <- as.character(finishedlist$id)
      if (identical(save_to_file, FALSE)) {
        res <- curl_fetch_memory(as.character(finishedlist$resultUrl[res$id == 
                                                          finishedlist$id]))
        return(rawToChar(res$content))
      }
      curl_download(as.character(finishedlist$resultUrl[res$id == finishedlist$id]), 
                    destfile = paste0(output_dir, unlist(strsplit(basename(file_path), 
                                                                  "[.]"))[1], ".", exportFormat))
    }
```

I hope, it helps.